# Linq select image isDeleted != true

Tags: c#, linq

I wanna select images that `isDeleted != true`.
I have that code in LINQ, something is failing because I got all the images.

```
Wine wine = (
    from w in db.Wine
    join img in (
        from i in db.ImageWine
        where i.isDeleted != true
        select i)
    on w.idWine equals img.idWine
    where w.idWine == id 
    select w
).SingleOrDefault();
```

cshtml

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.ImageWine)
                                                                    {
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td class="text-center" id="IDProfile"><span>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.idImageWine)</span></td>
                                                                            <td id="Name"><span>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Image.urlImage)</span></td>
                                                                            <td id="Image"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/"+ item.Image.urlImage)" class="img-thumbnail" width="200" height="150"/></td>
                                                                            <td class="td-actions text-right" id="Actions">
                                                                                <a class="btn btn-simple btn-danger btn-icon table-action remove" id="Delete" href="javascript:;" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Remove">
                                                                                    <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                                                                                </a>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    }
```

I'm working on asp.net mvc razor.

Comment: What is the error you are receiving? How do you expect it to respond and what response are you actually getting?

Comment: Are there several images per wine ? Do you use EntityFramework ? Is there a navigation property in `Wine`that could allow you to do something like `wine.Images.FirstOrDefault(i => !i.isDeleted)` ? Can you show us the model part ? If this is MVC, can you show the controller's action too ? Also please fix indent of your cshtml

Comment: I'm getting all the images always, the images that are isDeleted = true or false.

Comment: How you possibly get ImageWine when you only select Wine?

Comment: Yes, I have more than 1 image per wine, I have like 2 tables Images and WineImages. Yes I'm using Entity FrameWork.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek That's why I want to know what model passes through his controller to his view

Comment: DB model [link](http://prntscr.com/fn96c4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what happens :

If you pass a wine as the model to your view, and you have a navigation property that allows you to get all images for a given wine like :

```
wine.ImageWine
```

Then your linq query doesn't do anything you want, because it isn't filtering the images. It only gives you the wine if it has at least one image which isn't delete.

Then in your view you could do :

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ImageWine)
{
    if(!item.isDeleted){
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center" id="IDProfile"><span>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.idImageWine)</span></td>
            <td id="Name"><span>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Image.urlImage)</span></td>
            <td id="Image"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/"+ item.Image.urlImage)" class="img-thumbnail" width="200" height="150"/></td>
            <td class="td-actions text-right" id="Actions">
                <a class="btn btn-simple btn-danger btn-icon table-action remove" id="Delete" href="javascript:;" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Remove">
                    <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought that as well, but I thought LINQ could do the work for me. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Well you could with linq get all the images not deleted corresponding to the selected wine, and then your model would be a list of `ImageWine` and not a `Wine`, so you would be able to do `@foreach(var item in Model)`. But this is only if you don't need other properties of the wine.